# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

The console outputs me this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". Any help is appreciated. Best help would be to understand my error in approaching this problem.

```
        ngOnInit() : void {
            super.ngOnInit();
            this.prerequisites = Promise.all([
                this.apiClient.getResources(ClientGroupResource, {order: 'title ASC'}),
                this.apiClient.getResources(SettingResource)
            ]).then(results => {
                this.groups = <any>results[0];
                let settings : ResourceList<SettingResource> = <any>results[1];
                for (let i : number = settings.items.length; i--;) {
                    if (settings.items[i].key == 'color_booking') {
                        this.defaultBookingColor = settings.items[i].value;
                    } else if (settings.items[i].key == 'color_recurring_booking') {
                        this.subscriptionBookingColor = settings.items[i].value;
                    }
                }
            }).catch(e => {
                this.handleError(e);
        });
        this.routeReady()
        }

       routeReady() : void {
        super.routeReady();
        this.activeRoute.params.pipe(
        switchMap((params : Params) => {
              return this.prerequisites.then(() => {
                return this.loadPageData(params);
               });
            }))
            .subscribe();
    }
```

[loadpage](https://www.ideone.com/8UYaiz) function code in the link

Answer (score 0):

You need to return value inside the belwo code

```
this.prerequisites = Promise.all([
                this.apiClient.getResources(ClientGroupResource, {order: 'title ASC'}),
                this.apiClient.getResources(SettingResource)
            ]).then(results => {
                return results;
                .....
            });
```

Comment: You can see the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbs7uv

Comment: issue might be, you are calling "this.routeReady()" in wrong place.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Basically,  routeReady function running before the promise return.